# Basic JOIN in SQL not working.. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to learn to do joins on SQL I have done everything as per the tutorial I am watching and everything I try returns error messages.

My project in bigquery is called: fluted-gateway-399023
The dataset is called: employee_data
The tables are called: departments and employees

I am sure it is my error somehow but would love some help on my learning journey.

I would like the query to run and join the tables with an inner join using department_id used to match the tables.

```
SELECT  
--table columns from tables 
  employees.name AS name,
  departments.name AS department

FROM 
  `fluted-gateway-399023.employee_data`

JOIN
  departments
  ON 
  employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

I receive the error message "Table "departments" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table)."

**Even if I try the following I receive the same error message:**

```
SELECT  
--table columns from tables 
  employees.name AS name,
  departments.name AS department

FROM 
  `fluted-gateway-399023.employee_data.departments`
JOIN
  departments
  ON 
  employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Answer (score 2):

I have observed following mistakes in your query..

```
SELECT
table columns from tables employees.name AS name, 
departments.name AS department
```

[*missing employees table name*]

```
FROM fluted-gateway-399023.employee_data**.employees**
```

[*append fluted-gateway-399023.employee_data before departments too.*]

```
JOIN **fluted-gateway-399023.employee_data.**departments  
ON employees.department_id = 
departments.department_id
```

**Edit:** Updated query after removing mistakes.

```
SELECT
employees.name AS name,
departments.name AS department
FROM
fluted-gateway-399023.employee_data.employees AS employees
JOIN
fluted-gateway-399023.employee_data.departments AS departments
ON
employees.department_id = departments.department_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand. Is there any reason the [*append fluted-gateway-399023.employee_data before departments too.*] is included in the JOIN section as opposed to the from section?

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it readable. Text in [] were my comments on your missing code. And text in between ** is the missing value in your query.

Comment: On a side note: It is superfluous to give the tables alias names, when the alias names equal the table names.